# Server loading wrong page

Tags: javascript, html

I am using winSCP to connect to a school server where i must upload my website. I have my webpages in a directory called "website_html". I previously had my mainpage named "mainpage.html", but i renamed to "index.html". I went through all the other pages to ensure that they would load "index.html" and not "mainpage.html"

For some strange reason, which is driving me insane, it keeps trying to load "mainpage.html" when i click on "logo.png" or "mainpage.png", even after i refresh the server, the webpage, etc. I put comments on the lines that are triggering this. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>David's Music: Contact</title>

    <style type = "text/css">
        html,body
        {
            height:100%;
            background: url(images/mainBackground.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        hr
        {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            height: 2px;
        }
    </style>

</head> 
<body style = "background-image:url(images/mainBackground.jpg); background_repeat:no-repeat;">
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <div id="header" style="color:white; width:100%; text-align:center;">
        <a href="index.html"><img src = "images/logo.png" alt = "David's Music"></a> *//CLICKING HERE TRIES TO LOAD "mainpage.html"*
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div id="menu" style="color:white;width:19.5%;float:left;">
            <a href = "index.html"><img src = "images/mainpage.png" alt = "Main Page"></a> *//CLICKING HERE TRIES TO LOAD "mainpage.html"*
            <br>
            <a href="repairs.html"><img src = "images/repairs.png" alt = "Repairs"></a>
            <br>
            <img src = "images/contactus.png" alt = "Contact Us">
            <br>
            <a href="hours.html"><img src = "images/hours.png" alt = "Hours and Directions"></a>
            <br>
            <a href="lessons.html"><img src = "images/lessons.png" alt = "Lessons"></a>
            <br>
    </div>
    <div id="content" style = "color:white; height:100%; width:70%; float:left;">
        <form style = "color: white;">
            First name: <INPUT TYPE = "text" NAME = "firstname">
            <br>
            Last name: <INPUT TYPE = "text" NAME = "lastname">
            <br>
            Email Address: <INPUT TYPE = "text" NAME = "email">
            <br>
            What type of question?
            <br>
            <INPUT TYPE = "CHECKBOX" NAME = "question" VALUE = "repairs">Repairs.
            <br>
            <INPUT TYPE = "CHECKBOX" NAME = "question" VALUE = "lessons">Lessons.
            <br>
            <INPUT TYPE = "CHECKBOX" NAME = "question" VALUE = "other">Other.
            <br>
            Write your question here:
            <br>
            <textarea  name = "questions" rows="4" cols="50">Write your question here.</textarea> 
        </form>
        <form name="input">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form> 
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any ideas why on earth this is happening? I mean its no joke, there is not a single line of code anywhere saying to load "mainpage.html"... but yet it keeps trying to load it.

Comment: *What* keeps trying to load it?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache and then reloading the page to see if it changes?

Comment: Sorry I edited it and added some comments to show you where it is trying to load it.

Comment: I will try clearing my cache right now and let you know if that works.

Comment: Yup, clearing the cache did it...Thank you so much, I will have to keep in mind to do that next time before I start yelling at the screen...